# Adding new exception types to the WCF 4 routing service error handling

Tags: wcf, routes, error-handling

I am working on a prototype using WCF 4 routing services to create a pass through router, leveraging the error handling functionality

I have a requirement where if a WCF service generates a custom exception (in this scenario it is called a notPrimaryException), it should be handled in the same way as a communication exception is handled in WCF4 routing services error handling, that is, the message should be resent to the endpoints in the backup list.

Now I understand that this custom exception is returned from the service to the router as a fault exception at the message layer as opposed to a communication exception being returned at the transport layer.

I have tried using message inspectors and the IErrorHandler interface (ProvideFault and Handle Error) to identify if the notPrimaryException is occurring at the router but nothing is being picked up until it returns to the client as an unhandled fault exception. I was hoping to intercept this fault somewhere on the router and resend the message accordingly but I don't know if there are any appropriate behaviors.

Is there a way to shoehorn additional exception/fault types into the error handling infrastructure or is there another approach I may have overlooked?

Thanks and Regards,

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You should not be handling application errors on the router.  Generally, the application developer has placed FaultExceptions on the service with the expectation of being able to handle them on the client.

If the FaultException is not received by the client, how does the client know what/anything went wrong?

The only errors you should be handling on the router are transport layer exceptions, application exceptions should be handled in the application.

Comment: Greg, thanks for your input. Ok, returning an application error doesn't seem to be the correct approach. For all intents and purposes, the exception I am trying to return should be a transport layer exception. The issue I am having is how do I throw this exception, allowing the router to intercept it and execute its error handling functionality?

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what would cause these exceptions?  A transport layer error would be the machine being offline, or authentication failing, or signal interruption. I don't think you'll be able to do what you are trying to do, but you might be able to meet your goals by going with a more standard approach.

Comment: Greg, we have the concept of Primary and Secondary server pairs. These server pairs switch roles (i.e. when Primary becomes secondary, the secondary changes to primary). Services should only be processed on the primary server so if the primary server becomes secondary, the old secondary becomes primary and all service requests should be redirected to this new primary. This should be transparent to the client hence the router is taking responsibility of switching between servers. It doesn't make sense for us to return this information to the client

Comment: OK that makes sense.  I would be looking for a way to make the transport layer handle the switching.  Whether this is with some sort of rule on the router, a load balancer, or a redirect in IIS I am not sure.  Someone on ServerFault might have a better idea.  I don't think you'll get there by throwing exceptions in WCF.